# Simple HDF5 C++ issue

Tags: c++, ubuntu, hdf5

I'm trying to use execute a basic C++ script ([here](https://gist.github.com/YukiSakamoto/6319458)). I believe I've installed the HDF5 library correctly using:

`sudo apt install libhdf5-dev`

When I first tried to compile the code using:

`g++ hdf5_simple.cpp -lhdf5 -lhdf5_cpp -o hdf5_simple`

I got:

`hdf5_simple.cpp:3:10: fatal error: H5Cpp.h: No such file or directory`

Simple enough, I try:

`g++ -I/usr/include/hdf5/serial/ hdf5_simple.cpp -lhdf5 -lhdf5_cpp -o hdf5_simple`

And it complies with no issues, but when I try to run it is get:

```
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
Headers are 1.10.4, library is 1.13.0
        SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
        =================================

General Information:
-------------------
                   HDF5 Version: 1.13.0
                  Configured on: Wed Dec 22 18:04:31 UTC 2021
                  Configured by: ***@***
                    Host system: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
              Uname information: Linux *** 5.4.0-91-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 16:31:28 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
                       Byte sex: little-endian
             Installation point: /usr/local/hdf5

Compiling Options:
------------------
                     Build Mode: production
              Debugging Symbols: no
                        Asserts: no
                      Profiling: no
             Optimization Level: high

Linking Options:
----------------
                      Libraries: static, shared
  Statically Linked Executables: 
                        LDFLAGS: 
                     H5_LDFLAGS: 
                     AM_LDFLAGS: 
                Extra libraries: -lz -ldl -lm 
                       Archiver: ar
                       AR_FLAGS: cr
                         Ranlib: ranlib

Languages:
----------
                              C: yes
                     C Compiler: /usr/bin/mpicc ( MPICH version 3.3.2 Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 8.4.0-3ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-8 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu built with gcc version 8.4.0 (Ubuntu 8.4.0-3ubuntu2))
                       CPPFLAGS: 
                    H5_CPPFLAGS: -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L   -DNDEBUG -UH5_DEBUG_API
                    AM_CPPFLAGS: 
                        C Flags: 
                     H5 C Flags:  -std=c99  -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Winvalid-pch -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-c++-compat -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wshadow -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -pedantic -Wlarger-than=2560 -Wlogical-op -Wframe-larger-than=16384 -Wpacked-bitfield-compat -Wsync-nand -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wno-unsuffixed-float-constants -Wdouble-promotion -Wtrampolines -Wstack-usage=8192 -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wdate-time -Warray-bounds=2 -Wc99-c11-compat -Wduplicated-cond -Whsa -Wnormalized -Wnull-dereference -Wunused-const-variable -Walloca -Walloc-zero -Wduplicated-branches -Wformat-overflow=2 -Wformat-truncation=1 -Wrestrict -Wattribute-alias -Wcast-align=strict -Wshift-overflow=2 -fstdarg-opt  -s  -Wbad-function-cast -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-sign -Wpointer-to-int-cast -Wint-to-pointer-cast -Wredundant-decls -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-parameter -Wcast-align -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wformat -Wincompatible-pointer-types -Wint-conversion -Wshadow -Wcast-function-type -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wno-aggregate-return -Wno-inline -Wno-missing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-noreturn -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-jump-misses-init -Wno-suggest-attribute=const -Wno-suggest-attribute=noreturn -Wno-suggest-attribute=pure -Wno-suggest-attribute=format -Wno-suggest-attribute=cold -Wno-suggest-attribute=malloc -O3
                     AM C Flags: 
               Shared C Library: yes
               Static C Library: yes


                        Fortran: no

                            C++: no

                           Java: no


Features:
---------
                     Parallel HDF5: yes
  Parallel Filtered Dataset Writes: yes
                Large Parallel I/O: yes
                High-level library: yes
Dimension scales w/ new references: no
                  Build HDF5 Tests: yes
                  Build HDF5 Tools: yes
                      Threadsafety: no
               Default API mapping: v114
    With deprecated public symbols: yes
            I/O filters (external): deflate(zlib)
                               MPE: 
                     Map (H5M) API: no
                        Direct VFD: no
                        Mirror VFD: no
                (Read-Only) S3 VFD: no
              (Read-Only) HDFS VFD: no
                           dmalloc: no
    Packages w/ extra debug output: none
                       API tracing: no
              Using memory checker: no
   Memory allocation sanity checks: no
            Function stack tracing: no
                  Use file locking: best-effort
         Strict file format checks: no
      Optimization instrumentation: no
Bye...
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Following the notes at the top of the warning, I added `#define DF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK 1` and recompile and the same warning came up. Then I tried to add the path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH using`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/include/hdf5/serial/"` but still no luck.

I'm not sure whats going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags hdf5-serial` hdf5_simple.cpp `pkg-config --libs hdf5-serial` -lhdf5_cpp -o hdf5_simple
```

The command will allow you to build your program against the C++ **monothreaded** version.

For having ported hdf5 to Node.js (I am the author of `gdal-async` in Node.js), I can attest that it has some horrible quirks: it has two very important compilation options, the thread safety option and the C++ API. These two are not compatible and a stock tarball will refuse to build when both are enabled. The Debian/Ubuntu team went to extreme lengths to allow you to use both of them - as long as it is not at the same time - it is either C++ (they call this the high-level API) or multi-threading.

As if this was not enough, there is also the MPI-enabled version that you seem to mixing on top of it as I see from your configuration.

Do not disable any warning and checks and be very careful what you are linking your program with or you will be up for some very nasty surprises at runtime.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly!